# What is the difference between HOC and lifting state up in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

What is the difference between HOC and lifting state up in ReactJS?
In both methods we can share state what is difference?

Answer (score 2):

Higher order components generates new component based on a shared behavior, while lifting state up moves the state management to a parent or an ancestor component.

If a state is managed by a higher order component, it will not be shared by the component it wraps. For example with the following:

```
const useTemperature = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    const [temp, setTemp] = useState(0);
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} temp={temp} setTemp={setTemp} />
  }
}
```

When you create the component `useTemperature(Celcius)` and `useTemperature(Farenheit)` the state of those two is still separate.

If a state is managed by lifting state up, it will be shared by child components. For example if you have the following:

```
const Temperature = () => {
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <Celcius temp={temp} setTemp={setTemp} />
      <Farenheit temp={temp} setTemp={setTemp} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Calling `setTemp` in `Celcius` will change `temp` in `Farenheit` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

HOC and lifting the state up are two different things.

HOC is a component which can return the same component but with additional props and features. The HOC takes one component as an argument and it returns the same component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
       this.state = { name: "Parent" }
    }

    render(){
       return (
         <button>{this.state.name}</button>
       );
    }
}

const hocComp = (wrappedComponent) => {
    // some other features you can create here.
    return () => <wrappedComponent />
}
```

Lifting the state is a technique where you can share state object updates to several other components. In this technique one declares a state object at the parent class and exposes one method to child component and passes as a prop to update the state via `setState`.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = { name: "Parent" }; // <---lifted state in parent
       this.updateName = this.updateName.bind(this);
    }

    updateName(name){ // <-----method to update the state
       this.setState({name});
    }

    render(){
       return (
         <button>{this.state.name}</button>
         <Child onUpdateName={this.updateName} /> //<---pass one method to child
       );
    }
}

const Child = props => {
   const onUpdateName = () => {
      props.onUpdateName('Child'); //<-----trigger this to update parent's state
   }
   return(
      <button onClick={onUpdateName}>Child</button>
   );
};
```

Lifting the state would be very cumbersome when your application grows that is where context api or redux will be used for the same.